# Window Phone Controls How bind value of textblock depending on value from other binding

Tags: windows-phone-7

Let's say I have following class:

```
Class C {
    public string A {get; set;}
    public string B {get; set;}
}
```

and part of XAML file consist from 2 textblock

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding C.A, TargetNullValue=Not available}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding C.B}"/>
```

Now I have problem that property A can be null, therefore I use TargetNullValue to send message that there is no value but I also want that if A is null -> B should be displayed as empty string, otherwise B is just B. All must works without change object, because B would be use somewhere else when it's value would not depends on A.

In short: best would be if second textblock could be a listener to property A (targeting A when checking TargetNullValue), but if it going to display something (use Path property) it switch to B.

I'm not sure if it's possible in XAML or I need to do some walkaround, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recap of your constraints:

- you can't change the class `C`
- if `C.A` is null, show an empty string in the second `TextBox`
- if `C.A` != null, show C.B in the second `TextBox`
- when `C.A` changes, the second `TextBox` must update accordingly

Here is what I think you should do:

- Bind the second `TextBox` to `C.A` in order to be notified when that property changes
- Use a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to show either an empty string or `C.B`

Comment: I'm aware that you can't do that. Since Converter method Convert would have acess only to string C.A since it's binded to it. Anyway you help me to think of a solution.

I will bind second `TextBlock` to C, and use property change event. Fire property change when edit C.A, and cus binding is towhole object I will have access to C.B, by simply using property. Thanks.